# refactor try-catch across class hierarchy

Tags: java, exception, refactoring, dry, code-duplication

Suppose you have this code:

```
class Base {
    void method() throws Exception {
        try {
            //Lots of code here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //handle it (very little code here)
        }
    }

class Derived extends Base {
    @Override
    void method() throws Exception {
        try {
            //Lots of code here (same code as in base class)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //handle it (very little code here; also same as base class)
        } catch (Error e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

So, as we can see, the methods are the same except the derived class has an extra catch clause.  Is there a nice way to have a bit less duplicated code here?

Comment: I suggest to put your code in try block inside another method and call it when you need to.

Comment: Hm... that works I suppose.  Can't share the skeleton that way though.  For instance, imagine that both methods have an identical finally block as well.  (In the code that motivated this question, this is pretty much true: they have an almost identical finally block, with almost as much code as the try block.)  I could make a method for that too I guess, but, but I'm not sure if there's QUITE enough code duplication for me to be sure this is worth the trouble.

Comment: "The first rule of functions is that they should be small. The second rule of functions is that they should be smaller than that." (Martin, _Clean Code_, 2009, p 34). It is enough code to make into a method.

Comment: alright, alright, fair point